# Batching functions synchronously?

Tags: javascript

This is a tricky problem. Is it possible to batch function calls without waiting for the next tick of the event loop?

Derived example for simplicity.

```
let numbers = []
let total = 0

const addNumber = (num) => {
  numbers.push(num)
  compute()
}

// for the sake of this argument let's say compute is very expensive to run

const compute = () => { 
  numbers.forEach((num) => {
   total += num
  })
  numbers = []
}
```

This is currently what happens. `compute` runs after every `addNumber` because we need the total to be computed synchronously.

This is the example we need to work. We can only call `addNumber` we cannot directly call `compute`. Is there a way change `addNumber` so this example works but only calls `compute` once?

```
addNumber(2)
addNumber(4)
addNumber(10)
console.log(total === 16) // needs to be true
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why can't you call `compute` directly?

Comment: _"We can only call addNumber we cannot directly call compute."_ - and why would that be?

Comment: I doesn't make sense in this example but in the actual usage `addNumber` is executed in a special context that has a constraint where it's required to work this way. Only `addNumber` or some version of it has access to `compute`.

Comment: Ok so HOW can you modify `addNumber`? Can you change the parameters? Can you do other things in it before `compute` is called?

Comment: The one restriction is the parameters need to be a single number `addNumber(3)`. `addNumber` can be changed in almost any way you can think of other than that and it's executed in a context that has access to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. What I'd suggest is move the placement of your `compute` function so it calculates the value of `total` just before you need to retrieve it.

Any other option I can think of would entail some kind of asynchronous functionality, which you've said you don't want.

Comment: I assumed this was the case. As I know of no way to look forward to what the next event is on the event loop which is basically what I think would need to happen.

Comment: Is my first suggestion not an option? Can you not move the compute function to just before you need it?

Comment: Basically there would need to be an additional interface via `addNumber` or something where you would pass a flag to run compute. It would work but doesn't fit within the design guidelines.

Comment: You can find a **super dirty** workaround for the flag, for example if you have only positive numbers, passing a negative one would mean: "add the absolute value of this number and fire `compute`"

Comment: Yeah, might need to just throw away this interface for something else.  Just wanted to see if this was possible first. Thanks everyone!